# Intellij doesn't update to correct version of the dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate version 2022.1. I have the following pom.file:

```
....
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.dexi</groupId>
      <artifactId>webi-common-rest-service</artifactId>
      <version>1.15.61</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have run from the terminal and from IntelliJ the command  `mvn clean install`.
To check if I have the correct version of the library I run the command `mvn dependency:tree` and the result is as follows:

```
[INFO] +- io.dexi:webi-common-rest-service:jar:1.15.61:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.13.0:compile
```

It retrieves the correct version of the library(1.15.61). But when I open a file of that library in the IntelliJ it defaults to the wrong version as is shown below:
[image]

I have tried to update the IntelliJ to the latest version and download the latest patches but the problem still persisted.

Also, I tried to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ.  Despite everything I do, this IntelliJ does not show the correct version library.

Comment: Does it help if you delete .idea directory and reimport the project from pom.xml per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start?

Comment: Did you refresh your Maven import in IntelliJ (e.g. using the refresh button on the Maven tab, or the hovering refresh button that appears when you modify pom.xml)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Deleting your .idea configuration sounds like overkill.

Comment: I tried to delete the .idea directory. Also reinstalled IntelliJ and I am not able to get the right version.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried all the options in the maven tab, to download sources, and refresh updates. Nothing works.

Comment: Since the libraries are on a private repository, I cannot share them, but I will try to recreate a simple project with two libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by downgrading the version with IntelliJ. The version that worked for me was: **IntelliJ 2019.1.4**.

I hope that IntelliJ fixes this issue since working with older versions is not ideal.

Comment: It's unlikely to be fixed soon until you report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with a reproducible test case.

Comment: As soon as I find some time, I would try to recreate it.